# VBA search column heading in a sheet and return SUM in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to get datas from sheet 1 to sheet 2 with reference to the column headings With VBA.
For example:(EXCEL file)
[image]

So if I want to find the sum of fun1 person A with criteria 1 the command have to go and find the heading “sum of fun 1” in sheet 1 and choose the datas that are only under criteria 1 and sum it up in sheet 2 cell D5. (By using column heading reference instead of cell reference. The table range is A2 : U80. thanks.

```
Public Sub Match()




ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate


Range("Sheet2!B3") = Application.Sum(Application.Index(Range("A:G"), 0, Application.Match("Crit1" & "Fun1personA", Range("A2:G2"), 0)))
End Sub
```

I have tried it codes but it failed. i know that i havnt include the Row reference for crit1 , but iam not sure how to apply that to the formula.

Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a formula.
I'll assume that the table in your example covers the range A1:E10.

First we'll need to find the correct column using a MATCH formula:
`=MATCH("Fun2PersonA",$1:$1,0)` - this will return 3 as Fun2PersonA is in column C.

Next we need to know how many rows are in the table.  Assuming the criteria in column A has no blanks except cell A1 we can use COUNTA:
`=COUNTA($A:$A)+1` - this will return 10.

The above two formula will be used a few times within the final result, so will probably be easier to use *helper cells* to store the results (I'll just call them `ColumnRef` and `LastRowRef` for readability rather than actual cell references).

Now to set a reference to the first cell and last cell in column C.
`=INDEX($1:$1,,ColumnRef)` will reference the header, while `=INDEX($1:$1048576,RowRef,ColumnRef)` will reference the last cell.

As these can be used as references and not just values `=SUM(INDEX($1:$1,,ColumnRef):INDEX($1:$1048576,RowRef,ColumnRef))` will sum everything in that column.  It's the same as writing `=SUM(C1:C10)`.

But you want to use SUMIF, so we need to reference the criteria in column A as well.
`=INDEX($A:$A,RowRef)` will reference the last cell in column A, so `$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,RowRef)` will reference all values in column A.

#### Final Formula:

The final step is to stick it all together into your final formula:
`=SUMIF($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,RowRef),"Crit1",INDEX($1:$1,,ColumnRef):INDEX($1:$1048576,RowRef,ColumnRef))`
This is the same as writing `=SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,"Crit1",$C$1:$C$10)`

## For a VBA solution:

```
Public Function SumCriteria(FunPerson As String, Criteria As String) As Double

    Dim rTable As Range
    Dim rCol As Range
    Dim rCriteria As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

    'Update Sheet1 to the sheet name with your table.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'You may have to change how to find the last row/column depending
        'on any extra data on the sheet.
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

        'EDIT:  You could set your table as below if it's a static size.
        'Set rTable = .Range("A2:U80")

        'The first statement finds the FunPerson heading
        Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=FunPerson, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
            SumCriteria = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rTable.Columns(1), Criteria, rTable.Columns(rCol.Column))
        Else
            SumCriteria = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

This method looks at column A and row 1 to get the dimensions of the table and then uses SUMIF to count the figures.

You can use it as a worksheet formula:  `=SumCriteria("Fun1PersonA","Crit1")`
or within VBA:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim a As Double
    a = SumCriteria("Fun1PersonA", "Crit1")
End Sub
```

Comment: @Dareen  thanks for the answer, But the code still fails :(

Comment: No problem @Markie.  Are you trying to put add it as VBA code?  It's just a formula - no code required.  Remember to add relevant sheet references to the formula.  Also, is the top left cell of the table used in your example in cell A1?

Comment: i would like to do this in VBA andi have tried it the codes have been shared in the above question,the problem is im not able to put the row refernce in my code. and yes top left in the example is A1, thanks for ur efforts :)

Comment: Does the table in your example have anything else on the sheet, or is it just that table (could affect finding the last row & column of the table)?

Comment: yess this table have data in it. in the questions i have only provided the column and row headings.  You can assume that the table range is A2 : U80. thanks.

Comment: @Dareen  and what i would like to do is i have made a table in sheet 2 as a summary of sheet1, so example when i choose the column named Fun1personA  and crit1 the program have to go and search the datas which are Fun1PersonA as well as Crit1. the datas may change the abit in future  thats why i would like to use VBA  and the columns may change also thast why i would like to use the column names as the refernce, Thanks

Comment: I've added the VBA solution - both with a table that varies in size, or a table that set to A2:U80 (you can remove most of the code if it's a static table).

Comment: Both the formula solution and VBA solution will account for the data and size of the table changing over time, and for different criteria/headings.

Comment: I've updated the code (again) to display `#Value!` if the result is an error.

Comment: @Dareen i have tired the codes but its not really executing the outcome . Thanks for ur efforts :)

Comment: How's it not executing the outcome?  Does an error occur? Is returning the wrong figure?

Comment: Don't think I've heard of that error - what's the exact error message and which line does it occur on? (You can place a break point on the `With ThisWorkbook...` line by clicking on the left border and step through the code a line at a time using F8)